# Qt4 login window

Tags: c++, qt

I am writing a **login window** in Qt.

When the users clicks on OK, it should close the **login window**, show a **"Connecting to server..." Widget**, and open the **main window** once the *connecttoserver* method has done its job.

However, the **widget** appears only when the **main window** is shown, and disappears immediately (it shouldn't even close!)

How do I solve this issue ?

```
void LoginWindow::blah()
   {
   close();

   QWidget widget;
   widget.show();

   //calls to the "connecttoserver method"

   Main *main = new Main(student->getInfo()[0], student->getInfo()[1], student->getInfo()[2], view);
   main->show();
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QWidget is declared as an automatic on the stack so it is destroyed when the method returns. You want to declare it on the heap instead:

```
QWidget *widget = new QWidget();
widget->show();
```

Comment: Thank you, now the window stays open.
However, it still opens too late.
While the connecttoserver method loads, no window is shown...

Comment: It won't be visible on the screen until your application returns to the event loop.
You can try calling qApp->processEvents() after widget->show() but this is just a hack and the window won't repaint properly (amongst other things).
To solve the problem properly you want to i) make connecttoserver non-blocking or ii) call connectttoserver on a different thread.

Comment: Thank you, it works well now. I will take at look at threads in a while.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to atomice's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607311/qt4-login-window/1607327#1607327), make sure you have set your application's quitOnLastWindowClosed to false, or else your application will terminate between closing your login window and opening your main window.